# Inferring type parameter in method

Tags: c#, generics, methods, extension-methods

I have a hierarchy of classes in my C# library representing domain entities, all eventually descending from a root abstract class named `DomainEntity`. Some examples are `Package` or `Customer`. I employ `Create()` factory methods in each class to create instances. I also have a generic processor class `Processor<T>` where `T: DomainEntity`. This processor class also uses a factory method to be instantiated and performs business logic that depends on the specific class, hence its type parameter. Using this library, I can for example write code like this:

```
var pkg = Package.Create(/* various arguments */);
var pro = Processor<Package>.Create(pkg);
pro.DoStuff();
```

So far so good. Now I would like to write a method in `DomainEntity` that returns a processor for any particular domain entity. Something like this:

```
public Processor<T> CreateProcessor<T>()
    where T: DomainEntity
{
    var pro = Processor<T>.Create((T)this);
    return pro;
}
```

This method can be used like this:

```
var pkg = Package.Create(/* various arguments */);
var pro = pkg.CreateProcessor<Package>();
pro.DoStuff();
```

This works fine, but I find the `Package` reference in the call to `CreateProcessor()` a bit redundant, as I am calling the method on an instance of `Package` and therefore there is no ambiguity as to which class the type parameter should refer. However, this will not compile:

```
var pkg = new Package(/* various arguments */);
var pro = pkg.CreateProcessor(); //<-- this does not compile.
pro.DoStuff();
```

My question is:

Is there an alternative way to write the `CreateProcessor()` method so that the type parameter is inferred by the compiler from the object it is being called on?

I can provide a complete working Visual Studio project on demand.

Comment: Your "generic type inference works here" confuses me, as type inference isn't performed for constructors. At the moment it looks like you're constructing an instance of a non-generic Processor class. Please could you provide a [mcve]? That will make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You are right. I oversimplified my code while copying and pasting from Visual Studio. I'll update it shortly with a working version. Apologies.

Comment: I suspect an extension method will work for you, but I'd rather wait until I've got a concrete example to try it against...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Answer coming...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to create a generic extension method:

```
public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static Processor<T> CreateProcessor<T>(this T entity)
        where T : DomainEntity
        => new Processor<T>(entity);
}
```

That should allow you to use type inference just fine:

```
var package = new Package();
var processor = package.CreateProcessor();
```

That second line is equivalent to:

```
var processor = EntityExtensions.CreateProcessor<Package>(package);
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using a factory method:

```
static Processor<T> CreateProcessor<T>() {
    var package = new Package();
    T pro = package.CreateProcessor<T>();
    return pro;
}

// Usage
CreateProcessor<Package>().DoStuff();
```

I tried to find a way to use the type-specialization quiet a while ago and figured out that this does not work in C#. You can check [this blog post](http://kimkulling.de/2017/02/11/c-calling-a-generic-from-a-generic-with-surprises/)

Comment: That is what @CesarGon tries to avoid. Please read carefully.

Comment: Correct, because the typoe specialization in C# does not work when you go down the call hierarchy.